# How to convert rgb to gray but keep one colour unchanged

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylrtC.jpg) in which I want to only keep the green part and convert the others to gray scale.

[image: my image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from the colors in your image, that the greens are actually so close to grayscale that you'll be unable to see anything. Either way this is how you do it:

```
im = imread('houses.jpg');
s= (im(:,:,2)>im(:,:,1))&(im(:,:,2)>im(:,:,3));
dim = double(im);
r = abs(dim(:,:,2)-((dim(:,:,1))+dim(:,:,2)+dim(:,:,3))/3) < 3;
q = s|r;
imgs = rgb2gray(im);
imgs3(:,:,1) = imgs;
imgs3(:,:,2) = imgs;
imgs3(:,:,3) = imgs;
imout = zeros(size(im));
for i=1:size(im,1),
    for j=1:size(im,2),
        if q(i,j) == 0,
            imout(i,j,:) = imgs3(i,j,:);
        else,
            imout(i,j,:) = im(i,j,:);
        end
    end
end
imshow(uint8(imout))
imwrite(uint8(imout),'output.jpg');
```

if you want to see something useful you would probably want to do the following

```
im = imread('houses.jpg');
s= (im(:,:,2)>im(:,:,1))&(im(:,:,2)>im(:,:,3));

dim = double(im);
r = abs(dim(:,:,2)-((dim(:,:,1))+dim(:,:,2)+dim(:,:,3))/3) < 3;
q = s|r;
imgs = rgb2gray(im);
imgs3(:,:,1) = imgs;
imgs3(:,:,2) = imgs;
imgs3(:,:,3) = imgs;
imout = zeros(size(im));
for i=1:size(im,1),
    for j=1:size(im,2),
        if q(i,j) == 0,
            imout(i,j,:) = imgs3(i,j,:);
        else,
            imout(i,j,1) = im(i,j,1);
            imout(i,j,2) = 255;
            imout(i,j,3) = im(i,j,3);
        end
    end
end
imshow(uint8(imout))
imwrite(uint8(imout),'output.jpg');
```

which gives this as result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
gray_img = rgb2gray(img);
green_mask = img(:,:,2) > img(:,:,1) & img(:,:,2) > img(:,:,3);
gray_img3 = cat(3, gray_img, gray_img, gray_img);
green_mask3 = cat(3, green_mask, green_mask, green_mask);
output_img = gray_img3;
output_img(green_mask3) = img(green_mask3);
```

I didn't check it, but I'm quite sure it should do the work.
The only thing you might want to modify is the computation of the mask, currently it will include all pixels that are more green than red or blue, but you may want to be more (or less) specific in choosing which pixels to leave unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a purely hue=based approach, as you are interested in a specific color.
My approach would be to convert your images to the HSV colorspace and check the Hue channel.

```
img=imread('houses.jpg');
hsv=rgb2hsv(img);
% find the white areas of the image
gray_part=hsv(:,:,3)>0.7;
% find the green areas of the image that are not white
green_part=hsv(:,:,1)>(30/360) & hsv(:,:,1)<(210/360) & ~gray_part;
% create the output image
outimg=(uint8(double(img).*repmat(green_part,[1 1 3])));
figure;
subplot(121); imshow(img); 
subplot(122); imshow(outimg);
```

This will give you the following image (left: original, right: resulting masked image):
[image]

Of course, if you need to get the rest of the image in grayscale you may use the previous results as follows:

```
pixel(1,1,1)=0;pixel(1,1,2)=255;pixel(1,1,3)=0;
green_img=repmat(pixel,[size(img,1) size(img,2), 1]);
green_part=repmat(green_part,[1 1 3]);
gray_img=rgb2gray(uint8(double(img).*~green_part));
gray_img=double(repmat(gray_img,[1 1 3]));
outimg=uint8(green_part.*green_img + gray_img);
figure; imshow(outimg);
```

This will display the image shown below:
[image]